# UITabBarController not showing title of other tabs

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to make a UITabBarController programmatically. This seem to work, i have 2 tabs, the issue it does not show the second tab title in the RootViewController when it is loaded first time. How come?

This is when RootViewController is loaded:

[image]

When i click at the second tab where there is no title, the title appear:

[image]

When i go back the second tab title is still there:

[image]

My question is why it is not showing when the RootViewController is loaded.

my appDelegate method in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

MenuViewController *firstTab = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstTab];


FixtureViewController *secondTab = [[FixtureViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FixtureViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondTab];


self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navController, navController2];

[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

Comment: When are you setting the `title` in each view controller? `viewDidLoad`? Set it in `init`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add title to the view controller:

```
firstTab.title = @"Title to display 1";
secondTab.title = @"Title to display 2";
```

Comment: The viewControllers should set their own titles. IMHO it is bad coding style to set the viewControllers properties in a parent viewController

Comment: @der_michael how do you pass the title to child VC then? You have to use properties and pass data from parent to child if the logic (for example what title to set) is in parent.

Comment: It depends on your logic but the the title on a tabbar control is seldomly so dynamic that it has to get set from outside of the contained view controller... I just have a lazy loaded uinavigation item on the view controller that sets the title.

Comment: @Greg `UIViewController` has a property called `tabBarItem` which is specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You should set TabBar Title in `initialize` method, not `ViewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`..

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.tabBarItem.title = @"Tabbar Title";
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I was only seeing the tab image and title after I tapped the blank tab. It makes sense that that was the point when viewDidLoad ran & my tabBarItem code was hit

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning the title property in the RootViewController you should override the tabBarItem property on the first/second viewController. You can lazy load it to...

If you set the title property in the viewDidLoad() override it doesn't get applied until the view controller does actually get loaded and viewDidLoad() is actually called. You can check for yourself by setting a breakpoint wherever you set your title/tabBarItem.